# Issue with JS Promise and Pipe

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am trying to create a file and then zip it. However, the file is being created but the file that is zipped is empty. I am sure I am doing something wrong with my Promise but I am not sure what it is, any ideas?.

```js
const fs = require('fs')
const zlib = require('zlib');
const CSV = require("csv-parser");
const CSVOut = require("fast-csv");

async function processFeed() {
  let originalFile = await readFile();
  let manipulatedFile = processFeed2(originalFile);
  console.log('manipulatedFile ', manipulatedFile);
  await manipulatedFile.then(data => {
    console.log('here');
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/myexcel.csv`);
      CSVOut.write(data, {headers: true}).pipe(writeStream).on('finished', () => {
        console.log('finished writing');
      });
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('now here');
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/myexcel.csv`);
    const writeStreamFinal = fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/myexcel.csv.gz`);
    const zip = zlib.createGzip();
    readStream.pipe(zip).pipe(writeStreamFinal);
    // fs.unlinkSync(`${__dirname}/myexcel.csv`);
    console.log('Total Count ' + totalCount);
    console.log('Removed Row Count ' + removedCount);
  });
}
```

Comment: you are awaiting `manipulatedFile.then...` but there is nothing to wait for. This is probably not your issue but it is not necessary, since your last `then()` doesn't return a promise. So delete the await at `await manipulatedFile.then(data => {`

Comment: @Jozott A call to `then()` will always return a Promise. Removing `await` in front of `manipulatedFile.then` will break the Promise chain and must not be done.

Comment: `.pipe()` is not compatible with a promise flow of control as it is asynchronous and uses events, not promises.  You could wrap it all in some manually created promises that listens for all the appropriate completion and error events and plug that promise in your current promise control flow, but the modern way to do this is to promisify the `pipeline()` function and use that instead.  Code example in the doc [here](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback).

Comment: @jfriend00 do you mean wrap the writing of the file in pipeline() and then do the zipping?

Comment: @shellac85 - Please read the examples given for `pipeline()` in the doc.  It is a replacement for `.pipe()` that does much better error handling and can be easily promisified and will chain streams like `.pipe()`.  You replace your all your `.pipe()` calls with one `pipeline()` call.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that the `processFeed2` function returns a promise.

```
async function processFeed() {
  let originalFile = await readFile();
  let manipulatedFile = await processFeed2(originalFile);
  console.log('manipulatedFile ', manipulatedFile);

  const fileName = `${__dirname}/myexcel.csv`;
  await writeToCsvFile(fileName, manipulatedFile);
  await writeZip(fileName);
}


function writeToCsvFile(fileName, data) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(fileName);
    CSVOut.write(data, {headers: true}).pipe(writeStream).on('finished', () => {
        console.log('finished writing');
        resolve();
    });
  })
}

function writeZip(fileName) {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
    const writeStreamFinal = fs.createWriteStream(`${fileName}.gz`);
    const zip = zlib.createGzip();
    readStream.pipe(zip).pipe(writeStreamFinal).on('finished', () => {
        console.log('finished writing');
        resolve();
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this did not zip the file though

Comment: can you give me console logsof this code?

Comment: There was no output. Just the data of manipulatedFile (which is massive)

Comment: Does the CSV file get generated properly?

Comment: Yes CSV file is perfect just no zipped file

Answer (score 0):

Using Promises and `then` does not magically make the code wait for the stream to finish.
You need to wrap your streams into a promise, that is resolved when the stream emits the `finished` event.

```
async function processFeed() {
  let originalFile = await readFile();
  let manipulatedFile = processFeed2(originalFile);
  console.log('manipulatedFile ', manipulatedFile);
  await manipulatedFile.then(data => {
    console.log('here');
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/myexcel.csv`);
    
    // wrap the stream into a promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      CSVOut.write(data, {headers: true}).pipe(writeStream).on('finished', () => {
        console.log('finished writing');
        
        resolve(); // resolve the promise when the stream finished
      }).on('error',reject);
    })
  }).then(() => {
    console.log('now here');
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(`${__dirname}/myexcel.csv`);
    const writeStreamFinal = fs.createWriteStream(`${__dirname}/myexcel.csv.gz`);
    const zip = zlib.createGzip();
    
    // wrap the stream into a promise
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      readStream.pipe(zip).pipe(writeStreamFinal).on('finished', () => {
        // fs.unlinkSync(`${__dirname}/myexcel.csv`);

        console.log('Total Count ' + totalCount);
        console.log('Removed Row Count ' + removedCount);
        resolve();  // resolve the promise when the stream finished
      }).on('error',reject)
    })
  });
}
```

You should also handle the error case of the stream (listening to the `error`)  event and call `reject` in that case.

Comment: Thanks, this did not zip the file though

Comment: @shellac85 I can't debug all of your code. I updated the code to add the error handling. Now you need to add `.catch()` or `try-catch` block for your `processFeed` call to see if any error occurs.

Comment: @shellac85 the problem might be `console.log('Total Count ' + totalCount)` and `console.log('Removed Row Count ' + removedCount)`  because I don't see that those variables are defined anywhere. But without a [mcve] this is not possible to answer.